# Reusing filter instances in HBase

Tags: hbase

Does anybody know if filter instances in HBase can be reused?
I mean, if I need, for my scans, a KeyOnlyFilter or a SingleColumnValueFilter (this one with an fixed value which doesn't change between diffenent scans) can I instantiate those filters once (for example as instance members of my DAO) and reuse them in different scan invocations?

Answer (score 0):

The filter instance can be reused, similarly like an normal object, provided, the column family and column qualifier are the same for all scans.

Comment: mmmm looking at the source code of the filter I see the filter has more than column family and qualifier as its state. I see for example a boolean foundColumn member instance that is modified under the filterKeyValue(...) method. Probably my questions wasn't precise: what level of reusability? I mean, 1) can I use that in different sequential scans? 2) Can I use that in a multithreaded enviroment where several scans are executed at the same time?

Comment: Sorry...I was talking about the SingleColumnValueFilter